# How to get rid of unwanted InDesign style settings in paragraph style options?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I originated a design project with stylesheets years ago. The project has since been resaved by others as new docs multiple times in updated InDesign versions, and is now back with me. I want to clean up the style sheets.

At some time, stylesheets acquired extra settings such as: “shading color: C=100 M=0 Y=0 K=0 + shading tint: -1% + border gap color: (Text Color) + Mojikumi: line end all 1/2 em + Kinsoku: Hard Kinsoku + border top left corner radius: Op1 + border top right corner radius: Op1 + border bottom left corner radius: 0p1 + border bottom right corner radius: 0p1 + shading top left corner radius: Op1 + shading top right corner radius: Op1 + shading bottom left corner radius: 0p1 + shading bottom right corner radius: 0p1”

Paragraph Shading is off, so I can’t get rid of shading settings. I do not use Japanese typesetting so I'm not sure where Mojikumi and Kinsoku come from.

“Based on” is set to [No Paragraph Style].

I tried selecting the text, used “Break Link to Style,” then created “New Paragraph Style,” based on [No Paragraph Style], but the extra settings persist. (Could the [No Paragraph Style] definition have changed in updated InDesign versions?)

The only solution I have come up with is “Reset to Base,” then re-create the style without the unwanted settings. Is there a better solution?

Comment: *Many* users do indeed reset to the [Basic Paragraph] style then annoyingly *add* options to *that* style. Problem with resetting to [No Paragraph Style] is you have to remove the internal overrides as well. So reset and *clear overrides*. Which basically wipes *all* formatting. I don't think I can answer better than @Wolff - just wanted to say.. I feel yer pain!

Answer (score 4):

I've had this problem several times. It doesn't really matter, but it clutters the Paragraph Style Options dialog and makes it less obvious what each Paragraph Style does. Sadly I don't have a one-click solution for you, but some tips to make the unwanted settings go away.

---

The only solution I have found is to manually "Reset to Base". One setting at a time.

Once the settings under *Paragraph Shading* differ from default, they will be shown under the *General* tab. Even if *Paragraph Shading > Shading* itself is ticked off.

So these settings (which have no effect because *Shading* is ticked off) will result in the mess below:

[image]

[image]

But if you tick on *Shading*, manually reset each setting to their default setting (compare to a clean Paragraph Style) and untick *Shading* again, the mess is gone:

[image]

[image]

---

The Japanese settings are trickier for me to help with. I *think* you can use the same trick, but it seems you have to have the "the CJK (Chinese-Japanese-Korean) version of Adobe InDesign" installed to even be able to access these settings. Read about it [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/composing-cjk-characters.html).

So my theory is that if you opened your document in the CJK version of InDesign and reset the Japanese settings to whatever their defaults are, the settings would disappear from the Paragraph Style Options dialog.

---

It's cumbersome and a bit evil. I hope someone else can post a simpler solution.

Comment: I believe (and I could absolutely be wrong) that the Mojikumi and Kinsoku have more to do with overall paragraph spacing and line wraps - certain characters are not permitted to start lines, etc. ( don't ask me what those character are `:)` )

Comment: @Scott, yes, but it seems that if you have the CJK version of InDesign, you will have some settings available in *Paragraph Style Options* that you can't normally access. And you can't reset settings to default, which you can't access. I'm not able to test it since I don't have that version. ‍♂️

Comment: Me either... My point, I think, was they most likely won't effect much (in English). But.. if there's an odd place where something won't wrap as expected, that may be why.

Comment: @Scott, Ahh now I follow you. I think this question is mainly about removing the display of unwanted settings which have no effect.

Comment: @Wolff, your assessment is correct, that “it doesn't really matter” yet the extra settings are a “mess,” not helpful when juggling projects with a lot of moving parts when clarity makes a job easier. When I created the original project, “Paragraph Shading” was not a feature, (not sure about the Japanese settings). I'm wondering if the setting absence in the imported older style sheets causes it to be flagged as a modification. I will “reset to base” unless an easier remedy shows up later. I expect the situation will come up again... Thanks, all.